# Different geom_smooth and lm() estimates in R: forgot to add base slope and interaction slope together

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I'm trying to figure out why my `lm()` estimates are different than the `geom_smooth` for the same data and formula.  Specifically the slope for my grouping variable "cat" level 5 is >0 in the `lm()` output, but <0 in the geom_smooth (and hence the plot does not appear to reflect the summary table).

Here are [the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9G2lscuKZF-a0lXVUpPd3E4UzQ/view).  (Easier than coming up with example data that behave similarly.)

The model: `summary(lm(data=df, y~x*cat))`

Notice the slope for `x:cat5` is >0.

The plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=cat)) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", show.legend=FALSE) +
    facet_wrap(~cat, nrow=1) +
    geom_point(aes(color=color)
```

Get the geom_smooth estimates (following @Pedro Aphalo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)):

```
library(ggpmisc)     
my.formula <- y~x
plt + stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula, 
            aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
            parse = TRUE)
```

Notice the slope in facet 5 is <0.  Are `lm()` and `geom_smooth` using a different sum of squares or something?  Which version do I report in a paper?  If possible, I'd like to get the two to agree so I can use the plot with `geom_smooth` and the summary table from `lm()` in the paper.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the output from `summary` for the data (and the model) so we can be sure we've read the data in correctly.

Comment: @Spacedman, your output below confirms you've read the data correctly.  I'm not going to update the question with the output since you solved the question below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all looks right to me. The summary lines for cat5 are:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.932248   0.053131  36.368  < 2e-16 ***
x           -0.006651   0.001962  -3.389 0.000721 ***
...
cat5        -1.080554   0.075138 -14.381  < 2e-16 ***
...
x:cat5       0.005602   0.002775   2.019 0.043720 *
```

Which means the slope for cat5 is the overall slope for x plus the slope for the x:cat5 interaction:

```
> -0.006651+0.005602
[1] -0.001049
```

and on the plot I see -0.00105

The intercept is shown as 0.852 which is

```
> 1.932248+(-1.080554)
[1] 0.851694
```

So as far as I can see, the two things agree.

Comment: Oh my gosh, @Spacedman.  (Self forehead slap!)  Thank you for catching my simple mistake.  I was forgetting to add the x slope to the interaction slope!  Many thanks!!!